# Datamapper for composite key lookup not working?

Tags: datamapper

I tried using this `.get` method and it doesn't work. Any idea why? This is from the docs:

```
Zoo.get('DFW')
Zoo.get('Metro', 'DFW')
```

I assume that the Zoo model has a name column that has a name like "DFW" (David foster wallace?).

It doesn't work though when I try this syntax is terminal. All the get method seems to accept is a primary key.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Java? C#? Perl?

Comment: Also, if you provide a link to the docs you're talking about, it will gives us a lot more context. Thanks!